# Quadrature Error for Trapezoidal Rule

Tags: numerical-methods

> **Question:**
> If the trapezoidal rule is used to approximate the integral of the function $f$ over the interval $[a,b]$ with 201 evenly spaced dissection points, estimate the quadrature error for
>
> $$\int_0^1log(1+x^2)dx$$

For this style of question would I use the formula

$$error \le \sum_{i=1}^{N} \frac{-1}{12}\left(\frac{b-a}{N}\right)^3 f''(c_i)$$

to find the error?

Where N is the number of equal length intervals, [a,b] is the full inteval, $c_i$ is the midpoint of each interval and $f$ is $log(1+x^2)$.

If this is the case, how do I find $c_i$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding up the estimates for the *local* errors, we can use the standard expression for the global error, which in general is 
$$-\frac{(b-a)^3}{12N^2}f''(c),$$
where $c$ is a number between $a$ and $b$. In our case,  $a=0$ and  $b=1$. The number $N$ of subintervals is $200$.

Now we need an *estimate* for $f''(c)$. The second derivative is, I think, $\dfrac{2(1-x^2)}{(1+x^2)^2}$. As $x$ increases, the numerator is decreasing, and the denominator is increasing. Thus $f''(x)$ is steadily decreasing. It is equal to $2$ at $x=0$,  so $0\le f''(x)\lt 2$.

**Remark:** Or else use the local errors, and add them up. Since the second derivative is everywhere positive and $\lt 2$, the local error is always negative and $\lt \dfrac{1}{12}\cdot\dfrac{1}{(200)^3}\cdot 2$ in absolute value, so in absolute value the total error is $\le 200\cdot \dfrac{1}{12}\cdot\dfrac{1}{(200)^3}\cdot 2$.

Typically, the error estimates produced by this kind of calculation are unduly pessimistic. One can ordinarily get more useful information by comparing $T_{100}$ with $T_{200}$. The number $T_{100}$ is typically computed on the way to computing $T_{200}$, so it involves no additional cost.

Comment: Thank you, the local and global errors were confusing me a bit but I think I get it now!

Comment: You can use the "local" errors version. The $N$ individual errors are bounded as given by your formmula, so their sum is $\le N$ times the maximum local error. For that maximum, maximimize the second derivative as I did.